# save table data for each user with nodejs(can't use databases)

Tags: javascript, node.js

I develop app for a course that I learn at the university.
I need to save table data for each user using nodejs.
i was thinking about creating an object that will contain each row data but i don't know how to save it at the server and how to load the data later.
can someone help me?

Comment: Please at first try to work with help of Google & then if you faces any problems with saving, then post the error or which portion you cant solve ... Then I think u will get help. I will must help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am giving solution using Nodejs & mongodb. So please at first configure mongo.

User schema on user model :

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose')
  , Schema = mongoose.Schema;
 var user_schema=mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    email: {type: String, default: ""}
  });
mongoose.model('User',user_schema);
```

In server code to create user :

```
 var user = new User({name : "Test",email : "test@gmail.com"});
 user.save(function(err,user){
    if(!err){
      console.log("user saved");
   }

 })
```

Comment: hi I can't use mongoDB. I should save the data as long as the session remains. there is a solution without using database?

Comment: You can use session middleware or you can use redis for this.

Comment: should i add it at the server code?

Comment: Yes you can use redis session on your server code.

Comment: thank you! I will try to do it!

Comment: Please have a look this tutorial, may this tutorial will help you : https://codeforgeek.com/2015/07/using-redis-to-handle-session-in-node-js/

Comment: If my anwer & resorce will be helpful for solving your problems, inform me after solve the problem. Thanks

Comment: I am still working on it. I will let you know when i finish